# VB.NET - cannot get Video Preview to work

Tags: vb.net, video, directx, directshow, owner

Overflow. I have an application which is supposed to convert a video via DirectShowSource.
I have a checkbox which enables a button called "btnviewcrop" which shows a new form called crp.vb for cropping/shearing pixels off the video.

Now, I have a Panel1 that I want to set as the owner (the video drawing surface) but when I set it to open, the application crashes (Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.) and I do not understand how to fix it.

Here is my button code:

```
Imports Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback
Private Sub btnviewcrop_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnviewcrop.Click
     Me.ShowInTaskbar = False
     Me.Enabled = False
     crp.Show()
     Dim cropperv As Video
     cropperv.Owner = crp.preview 'VS2010 reports that cropperv has been used before being assigned a value'
     cropperv.FromFile(labinputfile.Text, True)
     cropperv.Play()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you ever assign anything to `cropperv`. Did you mean

```
Dim cropperv As New DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback
```

Comment: No, I pulled this directly from DevX Source code, and whe changed to AudioVideoPlayback, VS2010 reports the type expected is 'Audio', 'Video' or 'StateFlags'.

I forgot to mention I'm working in .NET framework 4.0, and yes I have fixed the incompatible framework problems. (I already have a part of the program getting the height, width, frame-rate and length successfully.)

Comment: @Yiu: I have no idea what any of those classes do. My point was not the class name, but the lack of `New`.

Comment: Ah I see what that does now. I need to dim it as a "New" instance because it's not a variable, it is an object.

Comment: @Yiu: It's still a variable. A variable that contains a reference to an object, to be exact.

Comment: I have all the initial steps fixed and final now, thank you.
I also have a trackbar(vol) for audio, but when I change the slider, nothing seems to happen:

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
     cropperv.Audio.Volume = vol.Value / 100
End Sub

Comment: Nevermind. Turns out the audio property is valid between -1000(min) and 0(max).

Answer (score 0):

Good point, and if I do this:

```
Dim cropperv As New Video(labinputfile.Text, True)
cropperv.Owner = crp.preview
cropperv.Play()
```

Then all works out fine besides the resizing needs done.
I appreciate the help, Matti.